# how to make relationship on typeOrm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

How do I define a relationship?

```
@Entity('favoritesable')
export class FavoritesEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  favoritesableId: number; // foreing key ( ads id, blog id, user id )

  @Column()
  favoritesableType: string; // ads, blog, user

  @Column()
  userId: number;
}
```

ads entity:

```
@Entity('ads')
export class AdsEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // How do I define a relationship to FavoritesEntity ?

}
```

data example for favoritesable table :

```
{id: 1, favoritesableId: 1, favoritesableType: "ads", userId: 1},
{id: 2, favoritesableId: 4, favoritesableType: "ads", userId: 1},
{id: 3, favoritesableId: 1, favoritesableType: "ads", userId: 2},
```

how to make this relation on ads entity and favorites Entity ?

Answer (score 0):

[TypeORM's documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/relations) pretty clearly shows ow to make a relationship between entities.

Example pulled from their docs:

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToMany} from "typeorm";
import {Question} from "./Question";

@Entity()
export class Category {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Question, question => question.categories)
    questions: Question[];

}
```

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToMany, JoinTable} from "typeorm";
import {Category} from "./Category";

@Entity()
export class Question {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    text: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Category, category => category.questions)
    @JoinTable()
    categories: Category[];

}
```

Comment: my table not need pivot table.

favoritesableId is FK column as other table

Comment: There are other examples including `One-To-One` and `One-To-Many` on the docs site that I linked. Those should cover any case you could run into.